# How to merge the dependency jar files using proguard

Tags: java, swt, proguard

I'm working on a swt application for desktop and there are nearly 15 jar files as dependencies. But I'm not using many of the classes in jar files. This is resulting in huge size of the final jar file.

I'm trying to us  proguard to remove unnecessary class files and basing on the output from proguard there are nearly 15k classes in dependency jar files but I'm using only 300 classes. Can anyone please suggest proper proguard option to achieve this.